# CSS variable url fallback relative path different in Safari to other browsers

Tags: css, url, safari, background-image, var

The problem I have is I'm using a css file with a load of css variables to replace backgrounds and colours.  In Safari the pathing on fallback URLs breaks.

background-image:var(--somevar, url(../imgs/background.jpg)); in my css/base.css will evaluate the fallback relative to the css file in Chrome and relative to the HTML in Safari.

folder/myapp/imgs/background.jpg in Chrome versus
folder/myapp/background.jpg in Safari

I've made a repo of the issue here: https://github.com/warlockuk/safarivarurl

Absolute path isn't currently an option as we've got reverse proxies and other things pointing to the content so everything has to be relative :/

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Small update as a workaround: I've made the Vue Project that causes the most issue with this build its css into the same location as the html; this masks the discrepancy between browsers' root for the fallback CSS.  Still not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Only for Safari  for logo url relative path problem */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    :root {
        --logo: url(/img/logo_50_50_color.svg); /*(add your relative URL)*/
    }

    .logo {

        background-image: var(--logo);

    }

}
```

```html
<div class="logo">

load relative url in safari

</div>
```